# Possible to Proguard Code Used for Tests but not in Release?

Tags: android, proguard, android-espresso, android-proguard

Is there a way to use Proguard to comment out a line of source code so that it exists for tests but does not get into the release build?

I am working on an Android app and have ported tests to Google Espresso for instrumentation tests.  As a result, I had to add some code into the `/src/` tree to notify Espresso when the app is busy, specifically it is a broadcast intent which is triggered by a static (and stateless) method.  I would like to not have production code create broadcasts that only tests ever listen to.

```
IdlingResourceBroadcaster.onBusy(getActivity(), MyActivity.class.getName());
```

The solution that I am looking for would be akin to C's `#ifdef`...`#endif` which would wipe out the one-liner above completely, or alternatively, akin to `Log.v()` which still retains the one-liner above but treats the contents of the method as NOOP.

I am not familiar with Proguard but from what I have read this does not seem possible.  Any suggestions or links to similar projects much appreciated.